# Challenges faced in resolving Algebraic Loops in SIMULINK models

Tags: matlab, simulink

**Problem Faced:**

I have a SIMULINK model that has got two algebraic loops.
In order to overcome this I have set the model configuration properties as "warning".
The model runs well and has got the expected dynamics as shown in below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kxUq.png)

Now I need to convert this model to .exe which will be accessed by a GUI. 
In order to do so I have to break this algebraic loop by using a unit delay block else the build process does not execute EVEN IF the configuration properties of the simulation model has been set to  "none/warning". 
But in the process of using a unit delay block, entire dynamics of the solution changes which shows that its a numerical error as shown in below image..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG46o.png)

I request, somebody please suggest a suitable solution in dissolving this algebraic loop error without changing the dynamics of the model.

Comment: What about the simpler [**`memory`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/memory.html) block? What you have now, seems physically impossible, so you should really rethink what you are doing there.

Comment: I tried out using “Memory block”, “Transfer Function Block”, but the dynamics of the model changes drastically. Is there any other option?

Comment: But maybe this change in dynamics is correct? Especially the variant with one unit delay appears to be correct. Do you have a real physical system?

Answer (score 0):

In many situations Simulink is capable of solving algebraic loops and provide a solution, but [it can not generate code (see "Implications of Algebraic Loops in a Model" at the end)](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/algebraic-loops.html). If I assume your implicit goal of creating an exe is to run it on systems without Simulink, that is not possible.